# Java Spring Data App doesn't save sub-objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to build build service, which saves object with sub-objects, but getting error. In result object data fields saved, but sub-object not.

I have the next object. The main is Order and sub-object is Partner:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private int orderId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Partner> partners;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "partners")
public class Partner implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "partner_id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
    private Order order;
}
```

I use standard embedded method "save" from Spring Jpa Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface OrdersRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Integer> {

}
```

and service, which call this Repository:

@Service
public class OrdersServiceImpl implements OrdersService {

```
@Autowired
private OrdersRepository repository;

@Override
public Order save(Order order) {
    return repository.save(order);
}
```

}

Does someone have an idea why Partners are not saved?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the relationship owner is Partner, so that you need to save the Order first. Or you can put cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST on private Order order;

Comment: This helps, but then sub-objects doesn't have parent ids..

Comment: I have posted entire structure here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67230610/java-spring-data-onetomany-relationschip-error

could you please take a look what's wrong?

Comment: You should set the order to each partner