# Java Spring Data OneToMany relationschip Error

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, one-to-many

Could someone please help with one question. I have made objects structure as in documentation, but relationschip OneToMany doesn't work.

```
    Order:
    - Positions
    - Partners

    I receiving error:

    SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (order_id)' at line 1
```

Order:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "e_orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private int orderId;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String orderNumber;
    private int count;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "e_orders", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Partner> partners;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "e_orders", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Position> positions;
}
```

Partner:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "e_partner")
public class Partner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "partner_id")
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String street;
    private String city;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_e_id")
    private Order attachedOrder;
}
```

Position:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "e_position")
public class Position {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "position_id")
    private int id;

    private String guid;
    private String posnr;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_e_id")
    private Order attachedOrder;
}
```

Comment: `order` is a restricted SQL word

Comment: I've chaned to "e_orders", but still the same issue

Comment: share a generated sql, plz

Comment: You also have `mappedBy = "orders"` while the property is `order` (Partner + Position)

Comment: Yuriy Tsarkov. it crashes before calling create script. Its crashes directly on first stage of configuration  in HibernateJpaConfiguration.class

Comment: Dirk Deyne. I have tried, just have forgot to update here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive that the problem is in your `mappedBy` values, coz the value for the `mappedBy` should be the same as a property name in corresponding classes, not as in a `@Table` annotation. So to fix the issue just change values in `mappedBy` form `e_orders` to `attachedOrder`